# Is it better to develop more powerful rockets instead of seeking and developing new technologies?

Tags: spacecraft, physics, technology

I have question about Space Industry and Era.

I'm aiming to being Rocket Scientist but I think it looks like will be so hard to reach far planets with these rocket technology that uses Newton's Laws and conservation of momentum. Filling up rocket's weight's 80%-90% with liquid hydrogen and liquid oxygene and a small percentage of payload I think, it would be hard and inefficient way to reach much more far planets or stars. If you think it's not right, please describe to me. I would be very happy.

Due to this situation, I think to involve Einstein's Unified Field Theory - General Relativity Theory and the bending of these theories with quantum field physics theories result of the efficient way to manage the whole universe's time and gravity. So this way, there will be a technology that doesn't obey 3rd dimension's rules (Newton's way). We can manage the 4th dimension (time, as Einstein's way).

I want to devote my life to develop a technology and new vision to these problems. Do you think this is a good and possible?

Comment: There are middle ways -- technologies like ion engines, lightsails, mass drivers and various forms of nuclear rocket potentially offer travel around the  solar system more quickly and conveniently than chemical fuelled rockets, without requiring completely new physics.

Comment: Yep, that's true. However, these methods uses a fuel (energy) and generates thrust backed by Newton's Third Law. I try to mean, we should to remove or manage **time** because **time** is a substance of 3rd dimension, it defines and creates the distances (x - $v \cdot t$) and velocity (v - $m/s$). If we look this situation by 4th dimension's windows, approximately *8 light minutes* far Mars could take a single second to travel, in my opinion.

Comment: Conservation of momentum is a fundamental part of both quantum mechanics and relativity.

Comment: Ops, sorry. I don't have a good knowledge about Physics in general. Thanks for this information. What do you think about the question?

Comment: There's no reason to wait for new understandings of physics to come before we try exploring the solar system. Travel to the outer planets is within our physical understanding, if not our engineering. Have you heard of the [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive](Alcubierre drive)? Something like that, if possible, would be what we want for travel been star systems.

Comment: This is a good answer. Thanks up!

Comment: @Snoopy that could be a nice answer to the OP's question, consider posting it as such?

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  Your question appears to be primarily opinion-based, and there may be no "correct" answer.  I'm glad to hear of your enthusiasm; studying aeronautical engineering may help you to invent the next space technology!

Comment: @uhoh eh sure, why not.

Comment: @DrSheldon the close reason selected says: "but **answers** to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions..." Considering that there is already one, very nice fact-based answer present, do you still feel that this is true, and that this question needs to be closed for this reason?

Comment: @uhoh: The answer is factual and good, but the question is "what's better" which isn't a good type of question for SE.  If you want to improve the question, I would be willing to reconsider it.

Comment: @DrSheldon One might consider that "X isn't a good word" is not a good reason to close a question. Editing the question to *fix a word* might be a more welcoming option than closure. Why not help the OP out by showing some better alternatives to "better". Of course choose words that are objectively better, not only better in your opinion ;-) Either way, I think "**answers** to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions..." just doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refined from my general comment:

We don't need new physics knowledge to explore our solar system, whether the inner or outer planets. There's been considerable theoretical work on engines suitable for everything from Earth to orbit to Pluto and beyond. What you're referring to with most of a spacecraft's mass being propellant is the mass ratio: MR = (1 + lambda) / (epsilon + lambda), where epsilon is the mass of the structure divided by the mass of the structure with propellant, and lambda is the mass of the payload divided by the mass of the propellant and structure. The larger the mass ratio, the more payload you get for how much mass you're sending. So, how do we maximize the mass ratio? We choose engines with a high efficiency, or Isp (specific impulse). Basically, how effective an engine is at using its propellant. An engine such as a Hall effect thruster may have an Isp in the thousands of seconds, while an engine such as the Saturn V's F-1 has an Isp of about 304 seconds. The tradeoff there is that a Hall effect thruster has a pitiful thrust-weight ratio, and the F-1 has a high TWR. When it comes to intersystem travel, spacecraft have multiple factors to consider: launch vehicle, type of propellant, type of engine, destination, cost, availability of solar or nuclear power, and much more. In general, though, unmanned craft can afford long transit times with very efficient engines, while manned spacecraft should have a higher thrust to shorten transits.

Now, when it comes to interstellar travel, there are a number of interesting options. One is to take a large array of lasers, propel a lightsail to a significant fraction of the speed of light, and send it to another star system - with the proviso that unless it has onboard (and very powerful) engines, it will be unable to reverse acceleration in the target system and be captured by the star's gravity. Antimatter, if we could make it in sufficient quantities, would also enable interstellar travel in something less than a human lifetime. But if you want to go much, much faster, you would need something like the [Alcubierre drive](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Alcubierre_drive) to make the trip, and the physics there is very theoretical indeed - we don't know how to make the exotic matter required, and that's one of the least of its issues. I don't see humans traveling to another solar system in this century as being probable, though certainly there will be humans among the outer planets once we build spacecraft such as argon-fueled nuclear electric ships.

You may find [this table](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/enginelist.php#id--The_Drive_Table) of engines useful and informative. The site itself is a gold mine of space-related information, so I hope it proves intriguing and helpful.

Comment: I had a hunch you had more to say, but... wow!

Comment: @uhoh Given the subjective manner of his question, I figured I should try to answer it in a way that would give him a basis for more objective future questions.

Comment: The problem is, what about if you don't just want to explore the solar system, but want to explore _and travel_ around it _in reasonable times_, say under 30 Ms (~1 Earth year) to get to every destination including Pluto? That would seem to require still some considerable new improvements in propulsion technology, even if not interstellar-grade. E.g. just roughing by distance, with Pluto at ~6500 Gm and Mars at ~225 Gm that roughly entails a 1 megasecond transit to Mars as the ideal, maybe 2 if we let things be a bit less linear. Today's tech takes around 20.

Comment: Thus necessitating the development of technologies to reach speeds of around 150-300 km/s or so, which is stilll very much beyond the reach of chemical rockets.

Comment: ADD: Actually, it seems like it might be better, at least for Mars transit. If we take the 2 Ms total transit time as given and allot 500 ks for acceleration and deceleration each with a 1 Ms cruise time, i.e. equal time for acceleration/deceleration and cruise, at constant acceleration, then the distance covered should be $1.5 v_c t_c$, hence cruise vel is $v_c = \frac{D}{1.5 t_c}$ and taking $t_c = 2\ \mathrm{Ms}$ and $D = 225\ \mathrm{Gm}$ gives a $v_c$ of $75\ \mathrm{km/s}$. With a 500 ks accel time then that is 0.15 (km/s)/ks or $0.15\ \mathrm{m/s^2}$ acceleration maintained constantly

Comment: for a period that is the equivalent of multiple days, and then doing it again to arrive at destination, yielding a total _delta-vee_ of $150\ \mathrm{km/s}$.

Comment: Also, for a 100 Mg (same as tonnes) craft, that means a force of about 15 kN of thrust will be required from the engines over the acc. and dec. time. IIRC ion engines are in the N (0.001 kN) range, and of course chemcial rockets are too strong with insufficient delta V capacity. Is there anything that could feasibly target this intermediate range that we could develop in the relatively near future?

Comment: ADD: Oops, just screwed that up - $t_c$ should be $1\ \mathrm{Ms}$, not 2... I used the total time and that $t_c$ is cruise time! Thus 300 km/s, 30 kN ... OUCH!

Comment: @The_Sympathizer for much shorter transit times we’ll need technology like beamed power, fusion engines, or for extremely near-term tech, Project Orion. But then you have to ask: why? Historically faster transportation has been enabled and funded after establishment of the reason to develop them, not before. There’s quite a lot we can do with present-day or very near-future technology that could occupy us for decades, if not centuries.